# medical practitioner vs. doctor?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I've read somewhere this sentence:

> Consulting with a medical practitioner can reduce the danger of
> ailment.

What is the difference between a "doctor" and a "medical practitioner"? Is medical practitioner someone who may not have studied medicine in university?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Doctor* is a level of academic qualification; you can attain a doctorate in many different subjects.

The word is also very widely used as a synonym for *medical practitioner* (a person qualified to practise medicine). Most people, hearing someone referred to as 'a doctor', would assume that a medical professional was meant unless told otherwise.

Comment: I would also expect for most people that "medical practitioner " would include people with some training but not to the level of a fully licensed doctor. For instance an RN (registered nurse) would likely be considered a medical practitioner  by most lay audiences, although not one likely to have relevant expertise for the quoted sentence.